# WPF: How to freeze a ListView header row so that it won't scroll off the screen

Tags: .net, wpf, listview, header, gridviewcolumn

I am new to WPF development, I have a ListView and I want to freeze the header row so that it won't scroll off the screen when the user scrolls the list.
The xaml code, I have inherited, looks something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <DockPanel>
    <forms:BindableGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" [code snipped] >
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="ColA" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ColA}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="ColB" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ColB}" />
           [etc]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `ListView` already does this - it has an internal `ScrollViewer` that only scrolls the items and not the header.

The issue is that your outer `ScrollViewer` tells its child (the `DockPanel`) that it has infinite space available, and the `DockPanel` tells this to its children, so your `ListView` ends up taking up as much space as it needs to display all the items and the internal `ScrollViewer` doesn't show up.

If you take away your outer `ScrollViewer`, the `ListView` should pick up that it has limited space, and the internal `ScrollViewer` will appear.

This will obviously affect the rest of the stuff in your `DockPanel`, so I'd see what happens and go from there.

Comment: Brilliant.  Just the prompt I needed to get the ListView display in the way I wanted.  You don't need the scrollviewer in situations like these...