# in WPF datagrid view header fix in scrollviewer

Tags: wpf

Am new to WPF.After a deep search am asking this question.Am not getting relevant answer in browser.

In WPF insert scrollviewer inside that place one datagrid view and make headers of datagrid view is fix while scrolling either horizontal or vertical both.

If any one knows this please let me know clear code.
can any one help me?

Greetings.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review the [ask] section and [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF: How to freeze a ListView header row so that it won't scroll off the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659512/wpf-how-to-freeze-a-listview-header-row-so-that-it-wont-scroll-off-the-screen)